# Laravel Model in different Namespace not working with eager/related Loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

When I'm changing my Namespace for some models in my Laravel project, it doesn't work anymore when I'm trying to load related models.

It all works when I have it in the default Namespace, but I wanna change it - for some unmentioned reason.

Does someone see what I'm doing wrong? Looks like all fine to me..

```
<?php

# Foobar
namespace Hello\FoobarSheeps;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sheep extends Model
{
    protected $visible = ['name', 'is_alive'];

    public function farm()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Hello\FoobarSheeps\Farm');
    }
}

# Address
namespace Hello\FoobarSheeps;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Farm extends Model
{
    protected $visible = ['city', 'latitude', 'longitude'];

    public function sheep()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Hello\FoobarSheeps\Sheep');
    }
}

# Result
public function index()
{
    # Just returns the Sheeps, not the Farms..
    return \Hello\FoobarSheeps\Sheep::with('farm')->get();
}
```

The response of the index is just the names and the is_alive boolean of the sheeps. Not the farm they're related to.

Comment: have you tried `composer dump-autoload` to reload the models?

Comment: Do you want to change the root namespace of your application completely (`App` to `Hello`) or do you need a second root namespace parallel to the existing `App`?

Answer (score 0):

You must edit the file `composer.json` and add the new namespace corresponding to a folder in your project, like this example :

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Hello\\FoobarSheeps\\": "folder_name/"
    }
},
```

Then, you have to update your project using the following command in your terminal :

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

The Sheep class needed to have the "farm" in the visibles Array:

```
class Sheep extends Model
{
    protected $visible = ['name', 'is_alive', 'farm'];
```